# Squid cannot cache static files with query string

Tags: squid, cache

I'm having an issue here.
i setup my router with squid transparent proxy and also to do static files caching.
It can cache static files successfully. 
But it cannot cache static file with query string.
Example:
http://www.example.com/style.css => this will cache successfully
http://www.example.com/style.css?v=1.1 => this won't cache.

Does anyone know why and how to fix that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default configuration of Squid is to [not cache dynamic content](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/DynamicContent) (which URLs with query strings are considered to be). That Squid wiki page explains how to change this. Basically you need to remove the following line from `squid.conf`:

```
cache deny QUERY
```

and replace it with these refresh patterns:

```
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0% 0
refresh_pattern .            0 20% 4320
```

Comment: It changed in version 2.7 (2008), now squid does cache by default resources with query string : http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/DynamicContent